# npm update: pull from github repo not taking latest commit

Tags: node.js, git, npm

One of the packages in a project is based on an internal npm repository.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-library": "git+ssh://<gitrepo>#dist"
  }
}
```

Where dist is the branch to clone from. This "works" as in it install the correct version. However whenever an update happens to this branch I cannot update using npm? - I tried `npm update My-Library` but this just downloads the old commit, it doesn't shift to a newer commit in the same branch.

The only "solution" I found is to manually delete the library from the node_modules folder as well as delete the library entry in `package-lock.json` (or update the reference there to the correct commit).

What is the correct way to make a library follow the latest version of another git repository?

EDIT: if this is just a definitive "not supported" that's also enough of an answer for me.

Comment: SIDE NOTE: I personally prefer to use git hashes instead of git branches in npm dependencies. That way I'm sure I have the commit I want, and my dependencies are fixed in a point in time, making sure it won't break in the future.

Comment: @xurei well we use a specific branch for this. - Once we need more control over this it'll move to a private npm repository with semantic versioning. `npm ci` should take only package-lock into account, from which I fully expect to fix itself to specific commit).

Answer (score 9):

From my understanding and experiment, the problem seems related to how `package-lock.json` work. I setup a lib with one dependency set to

```
"fn-with-hooks": "git+ssh://git@github.com/hackape/fn-with-hooks.git#master"
```

and initial `npm install` would generate a `package-lock.json` that contains

```json
"fn-with-hooks": {
  "version": "git+ssh://git@github.com/hackape/fn-with-hooks.git#fa1e21a8ea2fd2b0b7ec5897b954266791b56ac4",
  "from": "git+ssh://git@github.com/hackape/fn-with-hooks.git#master"
},
```

As you can see, the `version` field is locked to a specific commit hash, and subsequential call to `npm install` will not change this version field, thus prevents "tracking" the branch up to latest commit. It's just how lockfile is supposed work.

Remove `package-lock.json`, (no need to remove `node_module/lib`) then `npm install` can resolve this problem.

My immediate thought is try to exclude this specific lib from `package-lock.json`. But the npm lockfile is a whole-sale solution and provide no such fine-grain control.

So the only option down this path is to disable `package-lock.json`.

If you still intent to use `package-lock.json`, one workaround is to mannually run `npm update lib-name` command to force update that lib to latest version. This will also update the `version` field in lockfile accordingly.

---

**update**

I’m not sure why `npm update` doesn’t work on your side. It works on mine. Maybe you want to double check if it’s indeed the fact, or your misunderstanding. Although I seriously doubt it is, it could also be npm version difference. I’m using v12.14.

I have another workaround, which I tried and it worked. You don’t have to delete the whole `package-lock.json`file, you can rewrite it to just exclude the record of that git-base lib. This way npm lacks the lockdown information, so it’s force to re-fetch your lib. The other lib records in lockfile remain untouched, so limits the scope of influence.

Comment: Can package-lock.json only be disabled for a single "time" - we heavily depend on package-lock for deployment? As a previous poster already noticed `npm update lib-name` does not update `git` based dependencies further than what is in `package-lock`, it just doesn't update.

Comment: @paul23 you really need to double check. Me and the other answer by Trott both observed the opposite behavior to your description. `npm update lib-name` **does** update git base dep.

Comment: See my updated answer for a solution that resembles one-time-disabling behavior.

Comment: @hackape `npm update` works jsut fine and I am okay with this, a strange problem I am facing is just that if I put `npm update` in `preinstall` hook of `npm i` it doesn't work and give error of `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 22: .: git-sh-setup: file not found`

Comment: The error message complains about missing `git` related binary executable. Try fix that first. I cannot diagnose your local dev env problem. Maybe consider a fresh install of git?

Comment: using a workflow like 1) update/push git dependency 2) npm update on dependent projects did the trick.  commit ids in package-lock.json are indeed the problem.  Thanks for saving me loads of time.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is not the behavior I'm seeing (although see last paragraph for a possibility of what might be happening). I created a module that prints a `console.log()` and pushed it to a `git` repository branch. My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "slug": "git+ssh://git@github.com/trott/slug.git#temp"
  }
}
```

My index.js:

```
require('slug');
```

I ran `npm install` and `node index.js` and saw the expected message.

I then updated the message, committed and pushed to the branch. I ran `npm update` and got the new message.

I updated the message a second time, committed and pushed to the branch again. This time, I ran `npm update slug` and it still updated the package.

My `npm` version is 6.14.8.

The one thing I did that caused it **not** to update is if I used different case, which I notice you do above. Your `package.json` entry says `my-library` but your command is `npm update My-Library`. Different capitalization. I did `npm update Slug` and it didn't update the module. Could that be the source of your trouble? If not, what might you be doing differently than I did above? If nothing comes to mind, perhaps you can try what I describe above and see where it breaks down for you? (Or is your test case already that simplified?)